# How will this affect chances of preventing SQL injection?

Tags: php, security, code-injection

I have posted about this before but never in this regard so please take a look:

I was told one way to do sql injections was to use 1=1 where someone can see all entries that don't belong to them.

But lets say i structure my query so that it also selects the user_id of the current user, would that work:

```
  $userid = Current users stored id in database;
  $postid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

And now lets assume that i enter: `domain.com/page.php?id='' OR '1'='1'`

```
Select article_name from table where user_id=$userid and post_id=$postid
```

Will the query still return everything or will it not since i have added the `User_id` barrier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` is for sanitizing strings only. It does NOT protect from SQL injection in integers that are not wrapped in quotes, so your observation is correct: What is shown above is indeed not safe despite `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

You need to either wrap your values in quotes:

```
Select article_name from table where user_id='$userid' and post_id='$postid'
```

or make sure that `$userid` and `$postid` are integers before running the query.

Comment: Thanks! what if the $userid is something like 42343AKJKLJKLDJ and $postid is something like 34kAja will it still work if i use int()

Comment: @Sam but then they wouldn't be ints, but strings, wouldn't they? In which case you can wrap them in quotes, and be safe

Comment: i am a bit new so i don't understand correctly.  integers are whole numbers but if i have alphanumeric ids would it still work then if i used int..?

Comment: @Sam if you have alphanumeric ids, your column type needs to be `VARCHAR` = string. And strings you can sanitize using `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: @sam: mysql has similar string-to-int parseing rules as PHP: `select 1 + '123abc'` will return `124`, exactly the same as PHP will do on `echo 1 + '123abc';`

Comment: @Sam if you use varchar, there is no need for int parsing, is there? Just put your values in quotes and escape them, no need to do anything more

Answer (score 4):

If you use PDO you don't have to worry about escaping data (in this situation):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT article_name FROM table WHERE user_id = :userid AND post_id = :postid');
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':userid' => $userid,
    ':postid' => intval($_GET['id'])  //Just to be safe
));

// You could also do this instead (thanks @Digital Precision)
//$stmt->bindValue(':postid', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
//$stmt->execute(array(':userid' => $userid));

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    //Work with data
}
```

For more on PDO see the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/pdo).

The problem with using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) is that as its name suggests it only escapes strings. It escapes the characters that can be used to terminate a string so that an attacker can't close a string and enter malicious SQL.
If you are stubborn and refuse to use PDO, you could use a function like [`intval()`](http://www.php.net/intval) on any unsanitized integers to ensure they contain only numbers.

```
$post_id = intval($_GET['id']); //Now $post_id can only be a number
```

Comment: Not 100% true - PDO is unable to sanitize table and column names, for example. And of course, you need to use prepared statements like you show in your example. Still, it's correct for all the OP's intents and purposes

Comment: @Pekka The key word there was "*you* don't have to worry." In this situation, PDO eliminates the need to escape the data. However I see how this could be misconstrued so I'll revise. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that PDO will enforce data-types behind the scenes? I've always explicitly type-hinted: `$stmt->bindValue(':userid', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: @DigitalPrecision I'm not 100% sure. Type-hinting would probably be the safest thing. Although if you follow best practices, the data should already be validated before it's passed to PDO. I'll comb over the PDO docs to see if I can find anything on how it handles data-type enforcing. From what I remember, it was quite vague.

Comment: @Pekka, what about MySQLi statements? Any better than PDO?

Comment: @DigitalPrecision On the page for `PDO::prepare()`, it says "helps to prevent SQL injection attacks by eliminating the need to manually quote the parameters." That indicates to me that PDO handles strings but not integers as you previously mentioned. I'll edit my post just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "I was told one way to do sql injections was to use 1=1 where someone can see all entries that don't belong to them".

1=1 always evaluates to true. I've only ever seen this done when the query being generated by the application has only conditional where clauses with no root where clause. Not sure what it has to do with protecting you from sql injections.

Comment: i was under the impression if a hacker used that he would be able to return all entries from the table...

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of this, if you ran the query with or without the 1=1 you will get the same result set.

Answer (score 1):

Your query would look like:

```
Select article_name from table where user_id=$userid and post_id=\'\' OR \'1\'=\'1\'
```

As other mention while i typing this, it is better to quote your values. So you will have:

```
Select article_name from table where user_id=$userid and post_id='\'\' OR \'1\'=\'1\''
```

This returns nothing, if there is not a post with such id.

So your query will not return every post from the current user. But keep in mind to quote your values.